# display user profile from mysql database with php sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session

am new here, i have an issue with displaying logged in user profile, hoping you guys can help, here is my code :

```
<?php session_start(); include 'dpconfig.php'
<?php $run = mysqli_query($conn,"Select * from user Where id = $_SESSION['uid]"); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($run, MYSQLI_BOTH); { }


    $showid = $row[0];
$showfirst = $row[1]; 
  $showlast = $row[2];
  $showuid = $row[3];



 echo  $showid; echo $showfirst; echo  $showlast; echo  $showuid;
```

Now basically this code gives me the details of the first id in my database even if i login different users, i need help selecting data from table name(user) to display logged in user profile, using sessions. Thanks

Comment: You're currently selecting *all* records from the table: `Select * from user`  What you want is to add a `WHERE` clause to select a *specific* record from the table: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: if you don't have a WHERE clause in the SQL statement then you will get all the rows in the database (in random order). If you want a specific user you need to add something like WHERE user_id = <something>

Comment: Your code posted as such, contains too many errors and some unknowns. Debug your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
$run = mysqli_query($conn,"Select * from user where username='xxx' and pass='xx'");
```

it will return login user detail.

Comment: You should be selecting by `id`, not user and pass.

Comment: i meant .user mean userid of current user

Comment: Even still, you don't always want to select the **current** user. Having a more general statement is the way to go, ie `SELECT * FROM users WHERE \`id\`=?`.

Comment: i read some articles and they said make use of SELECT * FROM users WHERE `id`= '$_SESSION ['id']'";, but it hasnt also been working

Comment: @Davies That would get the currently logged in user's profile assuming you were using the `'id'` (or in the case of your edit, `'uid'`) key to store the authenticated user's ID in `$_SESSION`. But you'd probably want something more general, like `$_GET['id']`. Be warned that that would open up SQL injection, though, so you should use parameterized queries.

Comment: @Davies Though, if you only want the currently authenticated user, you should be fine. As long as you're storing their user **ID** in `$_SESSION` under a key you know, just pull it out and stick it in the `WHERE` clause. You'd have to define "isn't working" if you want help.

Comment: pls guys i need help reforming the code above  to enable logged in user view their profiles in the database..Thanks

Comment: how do i store id in $_SESSION.. tried $user = '$_SESSION['id"]; any help pls

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this, you need to remember to check that the array holds values as well, then you can respond to it...

```
$conn = dbconfig;
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='$id'";
$check = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("err $id " . mysqli_error ($conn));
$check2 = mysqli_num_rows($check);
if ($check2 != 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check)) {
        $userid = $row['id']; // repeat for all db columns you want
    }
}
```

Sorry if there are any typos, done this on my phone quickly.  If you need further help gimme a shout.

Updated the code to show more information with the error message, to help you get to the bottom of why it's not working for you.

Comment: Thanks..but it says                                                                                    Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\dashboard.php on line 22
errYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: @Davies simple; your session array is never set/is empty and never started.

Comment: I started session already, just didnt copy it along with the code above..

Comment: Updated the answer for you to help with debugging. As Fred -ii- says check your variables.

Comment: Please am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$id' (T_VARIABLE) after running the above code, what should i do please

Comment: If you're getting that error then you've not got anything in your session. Change $id = $_SESSION['id']; to $id = 1;, then it'll always bring up your first user, so you can see as an example. If you are struggling so much with this I'd recommend you read up some more from php.net.